# Tableview cut from upperside in iOS in simulator

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

[image]I have a viewcontroller in that i put a Tableview and cell.
I applied constraint both of them as per needed.
From above tableview,there is a label.
My problem is Tableview cuts from upperside in simulator..?[image]

Comment: add screeshot here

Comment: Put a screenshot of Storyboard and Simulator!

Comment: show the constraint you set for the view controller.

Comment: Looks you didn't set any constraints.

Comment: trailing space to superview, leading space to superview,bottom space and top space

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: select your viewController in Storyboard

Step 2: Uncheck Adjust Scroll View Insest

[image]

Comment: I have solved this problem by  setting Inset of tableview like this: tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(74, 0, 0, 0)